# I have a ); showing at the top of all wordpress pages, will show on some admin pages as well

Tags: wordpress

on my wordpress site, I have   );    in the top left corner of the website, showing on all pages.  it will show also on some admin pages, but not all.  For instance, after updating a plugin, it will show there under the Update Plugins header.

Any idea as to which file to find this in and where it might be in there?

Comment: It's going to be in a theme or plugin file. You will need to disable each plugin until the problem goes away in order to narrow down which plugin is affected. If that doesn't work, you'll need to change themes to confirm that the theme files are affected.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow :). Your question is a bit too broad for someone to clearly understand what could be the problem. Please take a look here: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and here: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Disable all plugins and see if that solves the issue.  If it does, enable them one at a time until the issue reoccurs.  You'll have found the problematic plugin once it does.

Otherwise, the first place I'd turn attention to is your functions.php file in your active theme.  You can switch to a different them and see if the problem disappears, to quickly confirm it that's the problem or not.

Comment: Thank you all for the answers.  I tried switching themes, no luck, and in the functions.php, I don't see it in there  - they all match up.  For the plugins, if I deactivate all of them and then re-enable one by one, will there be any problems once I get them all back on?  As in, will settings be changed or removed from some of them or will they show the same information again?  I'm a little scared to do that now.

Comment: You shouldn't have any issues with plugins being deactivated/reactivated.  Now that said, if you can perform a database backup first, I would advocate you do so.  Simply restore the backup should the plugin not behave appropriately after activating it.  Deactivating plugins do not typically invoke any data alterations though; it's not the same as uninstalling.